# image recognition not working properly for multiple target images in Wikitude

Tags: javascript, android, wikitude

I am making an augmented reality app using Wikitude SDK. Upon image recognition i am displaying a 2D image on the top of the scanned image. This process need to be repeated for multiple image that need to be scanned.

I tried following approach, but failed to obtain the result.
Approach 1:

I am storing the name of all the images that need to be scanned (target images) in an array and passing the array as argument to the aurgmented reality function
AR.Trackable2DObject like mentioned below:

var arr1=["Mango", "Guava","Papaya","Banana"];

for(var i=0;i<4;i++)

```
  {

   var getTargetName1= new AR.Trackable2DObject(this.tracker, arr1[i],
```

{

```
          drawables: {

            cam: [new AR.ImageDrawable(new  

          AR.ImageResource("assets/"+arr1[i]+".png"), 1, {

         offsetX: -0.15,

         offsetY: 0,

        onClick:function(arObject)
        {

        }
    })]
        },
         onEnterFieldOfVision:function(targetName)
      {
         // arr.push(targetName);
        alert(targetName);

        //alert("assets/"+targetName+".png");

      },onExitFieldOfVision: function onExitFieldOfVisionFn() {


      }           
      });
  }
```

In the above case object AR.Trackable2DObject is created,upon image recognition the elements of array are compared with the element of tracker(both are passed as argument to the above AR object) and based on any match a 2D drawable is overlayed using AR.ImageDrawable object.
The issue with above approach is that AR.Trackable2DObject is not able to read all of the elements in the array while comparing it to the tracker. WHich is therefore not overlaying any 2D drawable after image recognition is successful.
If someone can explain how the function call to AR.Trackable2DObject works with an array?

Please respond i can give more input to your replies.

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple target images in your target archive and you have only one overlay image you don't pass the whole archive as a parameter, you pass second parameter like that: "*". That means on any picture from target archive display overlayOne.

```
var pageOne = new AR.Trackable2DObject(this.tracker, "*", {
        drawables: {
            cam: overlayOne
        }
    });
```

If you want to build this overlay only on some images, not on all, make a naming convention inside your wtc file. For example instead of "apple" and "banana" name them "word_apple" and "word_banana". And in AR.Trackable2DObject pass as second parameter "word_*".

P.S. It doesn't work with array.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have tried using "*" and it works. However, I am trying to display a separate and unique overlay (a 2D drawable) for every target image in wtc file. For example, overlayOne for Target Image1, overlayTwo for Target Image2. Like that i have multiple target images. Can you please suggest an efficient way to deal with it?

Comment: Two ways efficient and easy. Easy create bunch of AR.ImageResource at the time that you open cam view and for each target image create it's own AR.Trackable2DObject (don't forget to change * to name of target image). And efficient you don't create nothing before picture recognized. Inside onRecognition check "response.targetInfo.name" or metadata, that you set beforehand to each target pic. And depending on that crate your imageResourse and 2DObject.